# Pasting bitmaps into as3 app

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, copy-paste

Is it possible to paste (as in copy/paste from the clipboard) a bitmap into a flash application?

I'm thinking about a level editor that lets you edit the tile images but wanted to allow copying or some quick way of syncing from an external file without them having to upload it etc etc.

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. But **only in AIR**.
It's a big security risk to allow any web flash to get access to your clipboard. You may have a password in there or whatever and any banner on any website you're visiting could get it.

Here's the documentation on how to implement it in actionscript3 in an AIR app.
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/desktop/Clipboard.html